# how to prove working of RS 232 full modem,RS 422 working PC to PC and LOOP BACK

Tags: linux, serial-port, linux-device-driver, loopback

Hello there I am a newbie trying to prove the working of RS 232 Full modem and also one RS 422( RX,TX,RTS,CTS)

These 2 ports are on a custom designed board and I need to prove they are working.

I am able to confirm the working at register level but I need to prove the working using softwares like Minicom or any other custom program.

How can I prove the working of these ports from one PC to a different PC using DB 9 connections and LOOP BACK too

Can someone help me with this? Do I need to use any extra hardware to prove the working of this in Linux?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You build the board, you power it on, you see if it transfers data. That leads me to believe the problem is that you haven't yet built any hardware and are trying to prove the hardware works using some kind of simulation. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Warren Young HEllo Warren the board is already fabricated and I just need to know how the connections are to be made,The board uses a Exar chip as Uart.And PLX 9030 as the Pci chip.the connections for the RS 232 FULL MODEM & RS 422 (RX,TX,RTS,CTS ) have been extended to a test connector.So the RS322 FULL MODEM has to be proved in loopback/PC to Pc.Similarly I need to prove RS422 ..hope you get my point ...Register level means I am using ioctl command to read/write directly to THR,RHR,MCR registers....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common type of serial port test is probably a **loopback test**.  Create a test fixture that connects output pins of the port to the input pins (TX->RX, RTS->CTS, etc).  If you do not have matching input pins for every output pin, you will need to do a three-way connection.

After you create the loopback, you will need to write software that exercises the pins.  If TX and RX are connected, you can send a byte and verify that it was echoed back.  For the control pins, toggle them and make sure the other side of the connection saw the transition.  **Make sure you exercise every pin of the serial port.**

**Note that you should run a TX->RX data loopback at multiple baud rates.**  It is possible for there to be a signal integrity issue in the design that only shows up at higher bauds rates.  It is also possible for there to be a bad signal connection on the board that is masked by inductance and capacitance at higher baud rates.  Therefore, it is a good idea to run a data loopback at the slowest baud rate, the fastest baud rate, and 1-2 in the middle.

Another thing you should do is a **baud rate accuracy test**.  This will prove the clock driving the UART is running at the right frequency, and being divided properly.  Transmit X amount of bytes at a certain baud rate and verify they arrived in the expected amount of time.  To get an accurate number, you will need to bypass any buffering in the OS serial port driver (e.g. use direct register I/O), and make sure to accommodate for any start/stop bit overhead (see comments below).

**However, a loopback test is not exhaustive.**  It only proves the device can talk to itself.  The device may still have some flaw (e.g. voltage levels) that cannot be detected locally.  So, you should also run some tests with external hardware.  Cable your board to another system and run a test (e.g. with minicom).  Make sure they can talk to each other.

**Even an external communication test can miss something.**  You can still have poor signal quality from your board, but it happens to be good enough for the other device.  **To accurately verify the signal quality/timing, you need an oscilloscope.**

While you are running communication tests, connect the scope probes to the various signals and verify the signal integrity.  Make sure that voltage levels are valid, that you see clean low/high bit transitions, and that the timing of the data pin appears correct for the specified baud rate.  (A scope can be a more accurate way to measure baud rate than the software-based method described earlier.)

Comment: If trying to test baud rate by data transfer rate, you must first determine the number of bit periods per transferred data byte - it is not 8, but something larger depending on start & stop bits.  See a UART data sheet.  Also, most modern OS's use buffered serial drivers, so you'll either have to find a way to disable those, measure transmit through to receiver, and/or measure enough data that the buffering is not a factor.

Comment: For a loopback test, you typically wouldn't have any flow control, so no start/stop bits.  But you are right about the buffering in the driver.  (Last time I did a baud accuracy test was under DOS with direct register I/O.)

Comment: start and stop bits have nothing to do with flow control, but with the way each individual byte of data is actually put on the wire.  They are extra bit period(s) inserted before and possibly after to permit the receiver to synchronize with the transmitter. Data throughput in bytes will be baud/character length, not baud/8.

Comment: Sorry for replying late ...my apologies ..I have followed the answers and found it useful ..thanks to all who have answered